# Getting a 3d object from connecting two parallel surfaces and then viewing the new side surface

Tags: mechanical-engineering, technical-drawing

I have two slightly different surfaces (circle with a part chopped off and a similar circle but with half of an ellipse in the chopped off part) and I want to connect them into a 3d object and then get the resultant side surface with its dimensions. How should I go on about doing this? Any good program suggestions?
All the help and tips are highly appreciated!

Here are some sketches. The upper left sketch shows the desired final 3d object from the side, the sketch on the left side under it shows a circle that has a cutout part with the elipse. The bottom part of the desired 3d object is just the circle with the cut out part while the top part ist the circle with the ellipse.

[image: Here are some sketches. The upper left sketch shows the desired final 3d object from the side, the sketch on the left side under it shows a circle that has a cutout part with the elipse. The bottom part of the desired 3d object is just the circle with the cut out part while the top part ist the circle with the ellipse.]

Comment: Welcome to engineering.SE! Can you add a picture of the two surfaces?

Comment: @OpticalResonator I have added some sketches.

Comment: @OpticalResonator I added image description to body as it was not visible before for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the popular parametric CAD programs for mechanical design are capable of this.  For this case, you can sketch the shapes and use what SolidWorks calls a Loft feature.

If you need more complex shapes, you can always add surface modeling entities.